# Kendo Grid Get All Table Records

Tags: json, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am trying to get all of the records that are in a database, and download them to an Excel file.  There are over 3000 records, but when I get the data from the Kendo Grid (I am successfully making it into JSON format), it is only showing the 25 records that I currently have displayed on the page.

I have Server Paging set to true, and like I said, my page size is 25.  Is there some trick I can do to get all 3000+ records put into the JSON I am sending, or am I stuck just getting the 25 that are displayed currently on the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By design, you should make another call to get data to export to excel file. This will keep the page light weight.

But if you still wish to go ahead with loading all 3000 records every time, you can disable server paging and enable client side paging, so that you can see 25 records on UI, but you have 3000 records in response.

Again you will need to separate the DataSource from the grid so that the grid can be shared.

---

Based on your last comment:

If you are using MVC (ASP.NET) you can pass FilterContainer object as parameter to container to capture all the conditions to filter the data from database.

```
public class FilterContainer
{
    public List<FilterDescription> Filters { get; set; }
    public string Logic { get; set; }
}

public class FilterDescription
{
    public string Operator { get; set; }
    public string Field { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public List<FilterDescription> Filters { get; set; }
    public string Logic { get; set; }
}
```

Build this structure in JavaScript to push the conditions from Js to filter the data.

Comment: That doesn't really help me, as I need Server Paging set to true.  Also, if I set it to false, I get no results returned and nothing in my grid.

Comment: To what I know, Kendo UI grid will always bring the records as set in paging.

Comment: I fiddled with it. I need the server paging set to false after all, since I have an autocomplete search field for the table, and if I had the server paging set to true, it would only search the 25 records displayed instead of all the records. I had to change the query a little too.